# jquery clone not working if user select other from the drop down the current text field disabled false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on jquery clone with my current code everthing works fine.

1. first scenario if user select **other** from the drop down the text
   field gets enabled
2. Second scenario if user click addmore button div gets clone
   perfectly with id when user select **other** both Original and clone
   textfield gets enabled actually  it should be only the cloned should
   get enabled not the enabled

Here is the current Jquery code

```
        var i=1;
    $(document).on("click", ".edu_add_button", function () { 
        var i=$('.cloned-row1').length;
        $(".cloned-row1:last").clone(true).insertAfter(".cloned-row1:last").attr({           
            'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
            'name': function(_, name) { return name + i }
            }).end().find('[id]').val('').attr({ 'id': function(_, id) { return id + i }  
        }); 
        $(".cloned-row1:last").find(".school_Name").attr('disabled', true).val('');
            if(i < $('.cloned-row1').length){
                $(this).closest(".edu_add_button").removeClass('btn_more edu_add_button').addClass('btn_less btn_less1');
            }   
        i++;
        return false; 
    });  

$(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function (){
    var len = $('.cloned-row1').length;
    if(len>1){
        $(this).closest(".cloned-row1").remove();
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '.txt_schName', function (){
    var cur = $('.txt_schName').index($(this));
    $('.school_Name').eq(cur).val($(this).val())
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {
        $(".school_Name").prop('disabled', false);
         $(".school_Name").val('');
    }else{
        $(".school_Name").prop('disabled', true);

    }
});

 $(document).on('change', '.txt_degreName', function (){
    var cur = $('.txt_degreName').index($(this));
    $('.degree_Description').eq(cur).val($(this).val())
     if ($(this).val() == "other") {
        $("#degree_Description").prop('disabled', false);
         $("#degree_Description").val('');
    }else{
        $("#degree_Description").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/9g6hq5cq/1/)

Kindly suggest me

thanks & regards
Mahadevan

Comment: the copied textfield have to enabled or disabled?

Comment: 1)  if user select other from the original div the textbox will get enabled

2)  if click addrow in the cloned div that text particular etxtbox should be in disabled once the user click the other from the dropdown of clone div this textbox should enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9g6hq5cq/2/)

The issue comes be cause you are using class selector directly. You need apply value only to the text box which belongs in the same container. Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the parent.

```
$(document).on('change', '.txt_schName', function (){
    var cur = $('.txt_schName').index($(this));
    var container = $(this).closest('.container-fluid');
    $('.school_Name').eq(cur).val($(this).val())
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {
        $(".school_Name", container).prop('disabled', false);
         $(".school_Name", container).val('');
    }else{
        $(".school_Name", container).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: one small query if i have two drop down your code is working perfectly fine but if i select other in the second dropdown the field is getting enabled now if i click the add more button the first time the text field gets enabled it was not disabling :(

Comment: sorry yaar it was working fine thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9g6hq5cq/3/)**

You need to refer proper element that has to be disabled and enabled.

Take the sibling of `select`'s parent and find the `input element` to be `disabled` as below:

```
$(document).on('change', '.txt_schName', function (){
        var cur = $('.txt_schName').index($(this));
        $(this).closest('.col-xs-6').next('.col-xs-6').find('.school_Name').eq(cur).val($(this).val())
        if ($(this).val() == "other") {
             $(this).closest('.col-xs-6').next('.col-xs-6').find(".school_Name").prop('disabled', false);
             $(this).closest('.col-xs-6').next('.col-xs-6').find(".school_Name").val('');
        }else{
            $(this).closest('.col-xs-6').next('.col-xs-6').find(".school_Name").prop('disabled', true);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you did, you actually change every fields with class `.school_Name`, to achieve what you want you can add `$(this).parents(".row").find(".class_name")` so it only change the current `div`.

```
$(document).on('change', '.txt_schName', function (){
    var cur = $('.txt_schName').index($(this));
    $('.school_Name').eq(cur).val($(this).val())
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {
        $(this).parents(".row").find(".school_Name").prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).parents(".row").find(".school_Name").val('');
    }else{
        $(this).parents(".row").find(".school_Name").prop('disabled', true);

    }
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9g6hq5cq/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way with targeting specific item using parent() and next() selector and also i prefer to access specific field instead of index(such as eq) for input.

```
  var schoolObj = $(this).parent().next().find(".school_Name"); 
  schoolObj.val($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {             
       schoolObj.prop('disabled', false);
       schoolObj.val('');
    } else {
       schoolObj.prop('disabled', true);
    }
```

Here is the [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/m33sjzx7/)

You can have a look for jquery traversing:

parent: https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Next:   https://api.jquery.com/next/

Find:   https://api.jquery.com/find/

and for full traversing: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/